# how to import contacts from various services like gmail or yahoo using python/django 

Tags: python, django

How can I import contacts of given email id/pwd from

1. gmail
2. yahoo
3. hotmail
4. etc

using python/django application. Please suggest?

Comment: What code do you have so far?  This is not "do my job for me.com"

Comment: why downvoting this question? he is surely not a native english speaker (see his About Me). i believe he is just asking for python apis for doing this! what do you want him to do? to reinvent the wheel and not to reuse code?

Answer (score 4):

for msn/hotmail : http://osdir.com/ml/DjangoUsers/2009-06/msg01169.html

for yahoo : http://rocketscience.itteco.org/2009/12/16/importing-yahoo-contacts-in-django/

others are in django-friends app (pinax app), importer source here : http://github.com/jtauber/django-friends/blob/master/friends/importer.py

google is you friend...

Comment: Note that osdir.com is a content scraper. You can view the original post [here](http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/4de310d48de90c92?pli=1) and the library it uses on bitbucket [here](https://bitbucket.org/justus_bex/django-windows-live-contacts)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into [pinax](http://pinaxproject.com/) an open source pluggable django app  collection which also has support for yahoo, google and hcard contact import.

Answer (score 1):

Amir Hussain,

Yahoo mail using captcha, so it will not works for any scripts or service unless they have managed service with the help of a third party for captcha decoder. So u have to contact a service provider who provide managed service.

As far as I know, Improsys is the first Address Grabber marketer and they have managed service. They have this tool available for Classic ASP, ASP.Net, .Net, Ruby on Rails, PHP, Cold Fusion, JAVA, JSP and Perl. Microsoft Outlook and Outlook Express.

Actually I am using their service. Their service is satisfactory but the cost is too high.